# 5x-32/5 simplifies to x-32/5?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on a Khan Academy problem and came across this and completely don't understand how this simplified. I was expecting it to be x-32, with the 5s canceling each other out. However, the answer was x-32/4, I don't fully understand how that happened.

Comment: So you supposed it simplifies from $\frac {5x-32}{5}$ to $x-32$ but Khan Academy showed it as $x-\frac {32}{4}?$ Well, the correct answer is $x-\frac {32}{5}.$ You can write $\frac {5x-32}{5}$ as $\frac {5x}{5}-\frac {32}{5}\implies x-\frac {32}{5}$

Comment: The correct answer to $5x-32/5$ is $5x-\frac{32}{5}.$

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ For this question, correct formatting is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Like people have mentioned in the comments, the formatting of the expression is critical.

Taking as you've written it ($5x-32/5$) there's nothing to simplify. Division has a higher precedence than subtraction, so you would divide $32$ by $5$ and your expression remains $5x - \frac{32}{5}$.

If, instead, you're asked to simplify

$$\frac{5x-32}{5},$$

then you would use the distributive property:

$$\frac{5x-32}{5} = \frac{1}{5}(5x-32) = \frac{1}{5}(5x) - \frac{1}{5}(32) = x - \frac{32}{5}.$$

The formatting of this expression makes it clear that you're to divide $(5x-32)$ by $5$, rather than just the $32$ by $5$. Another way you can declare this intent is to put the expression in parentheses like this: $(5x-32)/5$.

If the answer really did have a $4$ in it, I'm stumped.